# QGIS time manager: export video on Windows

Tags: qgis, timemanager, video

Recently, the time-manager-pugin seems to support video-export on Windows: https://github.com/anitagraser/TimeManager
However, I can't find any instructions how to install this feature. I updated to time manger plugin, however, it still mentions "only Linux/OSX" - so how to install or activate this feature?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The pull request with the feature you mention has been merged (https://github.com/anitagraser/TimeManager/pull/295) but there hasn't been a new release of the plugin yet. Therefore, if you want to use this feature already, you need to download the plugin from Github (https://github.com/anitagraser/TimeManager/archive/master.zip) and install it manually (i.e. unpack the zip archive in the QGIS plugin folder).

---

Update 2019-06-09: I've released TimeManager 3.2.0 with video export on Win now!

The video export is a two-step process: first the image series is exported, then ffmpeg is started to create the video.

Concerning **ffmpeg**: The tool is available from https://ffmpeg.zeranoe.com/builds/

Unzip the ffmpeg archive, e.g. to `C:\Program Files\` and add the path to the bin library to your Windows Path environment variable:

[image]

---

Update 2019-10: The video export functionality has been removed in the last release due to issues on all platforms and lack of resources for fixing them.

Comment: OK, I see - yes, now, the plugin doesn't mention any more the Linux/OSX-limitation. However, on export, I still get pictures only (png). I installed ffmpeg - however, it mentions requires ffmpag IN PATH - in whicht path, where to define it? - Great job, by the way, the TimeManager-Plugin!

Comment: Wow, thanks for updating the plugin! I have updated it to version 3.2.1. I installed ffmpeg like stated in the instruction above and here: https://video.stackexchange.com/questions/20495/how-do-i-set-up-and-use-ffmpeg-in-windows
Still, I have no video-output.

Comment: `PATH\timemanagercontrol.py", line 299, in exportVideo
              animate.make_video(path, self.exportNameDigits)
              PATH\animation\animate.py", line 73, in make_video
              subprocess.check_call([video_script, frame_pattern, outfile])
              File "C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS3~1.6\apps\Python37\lib\subprocess.py", line 328, in check_call
              raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd)
             subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['PATH\\animation\\video.bat', 'PATH\\frame%03d.png', 'PATH\\out.mp4']' returned non-zero exit status 1.`

Comment: In the above error message, I replaced the whole path with PATH because the comment allows only limited no. of characters

Comment: Can you run ffmpeg from the Windows command line?

Comment: Yes - when I type ffmpeg to the start button, there is a dialogue "run ffmpeg" - hower, nothing happens if I press it (which should be normal as far as I understand, as ffmpeg is command-line tool that must be run with some parameters).

Comment: Type cmd to the start button. That opens the command line. Then type ffmpeg in the command line. You should see some feedback from the programme rather than an error message that it cannot be found if everything is ok with the path.

Comment: Yes, everythin seems to be normal, no error message, just a list of ffmpeg versiion-/built-no. and configuration details. So installation seems to be working.

Comment: Back to office, I tried it here again on another machine - same result (error message). QGIS 3.6.2. - TimeManager 3.2.2. - Windows 10 enterpreise x64. ffmpeg runs properly in cmd

Comment: @babel please open a ticket on https://github.com/anitagraser/TimeManager/issues

Comment: Was this problem solved? I have the same error message but installation of ffmpeg is functionable!